# How do I update to Blender 3.0?

Tags: interface, blend-files, data-blocks

I just found out Blender got an update and I'm still using 2.90.1. So how do I download it, or does it just automatically do it? And will I still keep all my current stuff I saved?

Answer (score 0):

You'll visit:
https://www.blender.org/download/

Click the blue **Download Blender 3.0** button and double-click the installer when it downloads to run it.
[image]

There is an option when you install the new version to migrate your 2.9 settings. If you have any add-ons installed, those will come over as well, but be careful: they can cause crashes if they aren't tested with 3.0.